# How to find out Windows network interface name in Python?

Tags: python, static-ip-address

Windows command `netsh interface show interface` shows all network connections and their names. A name could be `Wireless Network Connection`, `Local Area Network` or `Ethernet` etc.

I would like to change an IP address with `netsh interface ip set address "Wireless Network Connection" static 192.168.1.3 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1 1` with Python script, but I need a network interface name.

Is it possible to have this information like we can have a hostname with `socket.gethostname()`? Or I can change an IP address with Python in other way?

Comment: May be: http://pythonhosted.org/ifaddr/

Comment: @RehanAzher No, unfortunately, this doesn't give "Wireless Network Connection" as an information.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a Python `netsh` API. But it should not be hard to do with a pair of `subprocess` calls. First issue `netsh interface show interface`, parse the output you get back, then issue your `set address` command.

Or am I missing the point?

Comment: This was my first idea, but I tought maybe there is simpler way, like for IP address `ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())`.